# How do I ensure that keys get mapped to correct values when using custom objects

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, stdmap

I am working with data that has the following Structure.

Points object are templated data types which consist of floating point values and represent 3 dimensional data.

If I wanted to access the data in a point I would do

```
Point3D< float > p[0] = 1.1;
Point3D< float > p[1] = 2.3;
Point3D< float > p[2] = 2.3;
```

Each point also has an index associated with it to allow for easy lookup.
The index associated with a point is unique and the reverse is true also.

I have 2 maps site_index_map which takes in a Point object and returns its index and an index_site_map which takes in an index and returns the associated 3d point.

They were constructed as below

```
std::map < Point3D< float > , int , PointCompare> site_index_map;
std::map < int, Point3D< float > > index_site_map;
```

where the "PointCompare" struct is defined as follows

```
struct PointCompare
{
   bool operator() (const Point3D< float >& lhs, const Point3D< float >& rhs) const
   {
       return lhs[0] <= rhs[0];
   }
};
```

I defined it like this because I understand that when using custom objects as keys I need to define a custom comparator.

**This is my problem**
when querying the the points associated with the first 5 indices of the index_site map and then in turn querying the indices associated with the points returned I get this

```
Vertex 0: [-12.862379, -33.685909, -15.792738]
Index: 0
Vertex 1: [-12.709168, -33.382538, -15.792738]
Index: 0
Vertex 2: [-12.862379, -33.382538, -16.249332]
Index: 0
Vertex 3: [19.727800, 20.137928, -27.370831]
Index: 0
Vertex 4: [19.930809, 19.790909, -26.942013]
Index: 0
```

(The number following Vertex is the loop counter, the associated point is got by giving the loop counter to the index site map)

I am really confused. Why does the map that maps points to ints always return 0 as the index of a point when the int to point map maintains the correct order?

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**: Providing additional details

The expected output should be

```
Vertex 0: [-12.862379, -33.685909, -15.792738]
Index: 0
Vertex 1: [-12.709168, -33.382538, -15.792738]
Index: 1
Vertex 2: [-12.862379, -33.382538, -16.249332]
Index: 2
Vertex 3: [19.727800, 20.137928, -27.370831]
Index: 3
Vertex 4: [19.930809, 19.790909, -26.942013]
Index: 4
```

After changing the <= in PointCompare to < I got this

```
Vertex 0: [-12.862379, -33.685909, -15.792738]
Index: 172275
Vertex 1: [-12.709168, -33.382538, -15.792738]
Index: 1
Vertex 2: [-12.862379, -33.382538, -16.249332]
Index: 172275
Vertex 3: [19.727800, 20.137928, -27.370831]
Index: 172437
Vertex 4: [19.930809, 19.790909, -26.942013]
Index: 4
```

Some of the indices became right. I am using this function to put values in the respective maps (pls disregard the lines pertaining to openmp)

```
void Put_In_Map(
                std::map < Point3D< float > , int , PointCompare> &site_index_map,
                std::map < int, Point3D< float > > &index_site_map,
                std::vector< PlyVertex< float > > &plyVertices,
                std::vector< TriangleIndex > &triangles
                ) {
    // Write lock to ensure data writes are single threaded
    omp_lock_t writelock;
    omp_init_lock(&writelock);

    // I know parallelization achieves nothing here, but just having it anyway
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
    {
        int i = omp_get_thread_num();
        while ( i < plyVertices.size()) {
            omp_set_lock(&writelock);
            site_index_map[plyVertices[i]] = i;
            index_site_map[i] = plyVertices[i];
            omp_unset_lock(&writelock);
            i = i + NUM_THREADS;
        }
    }
}
```

Printing my output like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Point3D< float > p = index_site_map[i];
        IdentifyVertex(p, i);
        std::cout << "Index: " << site_index_map[p] << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: The comparator used for `std::map` is usually *less than*, not less than or equal.

Comment: And can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Including how you add values to the maps, and how you print the output you show us. Also please show the *expected* output, besides the actual output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've made the edits, thanks

Comment: If you "know parallelization achieves nothing here", then why have it? Make it work *without* any parallelization first, without any use of OpenMP. When it all works single-threaded and non-parallelized, then add parallelization. The simpler the code is, the less likely it is to have faults. And do one thing at a time, make sure it works, and when it does continue to the next thing.

Comment: I got it!! You were right!! It was a mistake in the comparator. As it turns out it needed to account for y and z coords as well. Once I fixed that it became good and gave me the correct output
 [This](https://gist.github.com/thewickedaxe/8a75dd8168342313148c6692d9799893) gist has what I did, if you add it as an answer I will accpet it :), Thanks @Someprogrammerdude :) !!